# Tensorflow GPU CUDA Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I fear this to be marked as duplicate but I find examples with `libcudart` or `libcublas` but not `libcufft` (which is my issue).

I installed TensorFlow and I want to use the GPU. I, therefore, run the script on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1804_cuda_110) link.

When running TensorFlow to train a network I get the following message:

```
2021-09-23 11:19:22.158959: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-09-23 11:19:22.162563: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-23 11:19:22.162651: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-23 11:19:22.162730: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-23 11:19:22.162806: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-23 11:19:22.162989: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1835] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-09-23 11:19:22.163345: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

Using `tf.config.list_physical_devices()` I get:

```
2021-09-23 11:30:18.327648: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-09-23 11:30:18.329447: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
2021-09-23 11:30:18.329510: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
2021-09-23 11:30:18.329573: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
2021-09-23 11:30:18.329687: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
2021-09-23 11:30:18.329814: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1835] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

I have a folder called `/usr/local/cuda-11.0` but not `cuda` alone, neither I have an `extras` folder in it.
It is true that it says for Ubuntu 18.04 and I have Ubuntu 20.04.

If I try to run `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` as suggested [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04-4ee3ca4cb75d) I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nsight-compute (= 10.1.243-3)
                       Recommends: nsight-systems (= 10.1.243-3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Output of `whereis cuda` is `cuda:` (empty).

The output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.91.03    Driver Version: 460.91.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   40C    P8    31W / 300W |    626MiB / 11016MiB |     15%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1141      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 59MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1749      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                315MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1886      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               59MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1907      G   ...mviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2463      G   ...ble-features=SpareRendere        4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3825      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files      105MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4682      G   .../debug.log --shared-files       36MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20600      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       24MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I fear installing stuff to solve it and finish with the typical of 20 versions of CUDA colliding with each other.

Comment: Your istallation seems a bit iffy. The version of cude is very important. Tensorflow seems to be looking for CUDA 10? but you have 11.0 installed? I would suggest you clean up all your cuda installs and start from scratch, uniquely with the version of CUDA that is required by tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did as suggested in the comments and uninstall everything in a very aggressive manner:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge cuda
sudo apt purge nvidia-* 
sudo apt autoremove
```

I then followed the instructions to install:

- [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
- [CUDA Toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) (Although I think it's the same, I just added a command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-gds` which I don't even know if it was necessary)
- [CUDNN](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

Now it seems to be working.